# How can I count instances of character "x"?

Tags: counting

Let's say I have the following bit of code:

```
v = [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I want to know how many elements are in v.

My current solution, if `v` isn't too large, requires a bit of counting, but it makes for more readable code:

```
v = [0,0,0,0,
     0,1,0,0,
     0,0,0,0,
     0,0,0,0]
```

This is less helpful when `v` is large.

It also occurs to me that I could just pipe the line into the shell (assume it's line 1)

```
 :1 ! tr -dc ',' | wc -c
```

But this replaces the contents of line 1 with 15 (which is the answer I am looking for ... nothing undo cannot fix)

Is there a better vim command to count how many times a character appears in a selection/line/range?